# what is Haystack for Django?

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh, xapian

I have been reading about Haystack,Whoosh,Xapian,etc. however I didn't really get what they are exactly used for and what is the relationship between them.
For example, it is said that

> Enable searching on third-party apps without touching that app’s code.

Can some explain to me what these are used for maybe giving a nice link and simple enough to understand for a begginer.
thx

Comment: Solr/Whoosh/Xapian provide searching capabilities (full-text search, text indexing) for an application, and Haystack is a package that allows you to build search for a django application without caring about which of those engines eventually get used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Haystack](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/) is a different beast from Whoosh/Xapian/etc.:

> Haystack provides modular search for Django. It features a unified, familiar API that allows you to plug in different search backends (such as Solr, Whoosh, Xapian, etc.) without having to modify your code.

From [the FAQ](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/faq.html) (emphasis added):

> #### What is Haystack?
>
> Haystack is meant to be a portable interface to a search engine of your choice. Some might call it a search framework, an abstraction layer or what have you. The idea is that you **write your search code once and should be able to freely switch between backends** as your situation necessitates.

The "search backends" mentioned are search libraries which have their own API. Haystack provides a unified API on top (and independent) of any one specific search library.